# How to number program listings like figures

Tags: cross-referencing, listings

Is there a way to number program listings like figures and reference them? I have the following mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\autoref{lst:some_code}.

\begin{lstlisting}[float,frame=single,label={lst:some_code}]
if (i<=0) then i := 1;
if (i>=0) then i := 0;
if (i<>0) then i := 0;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

But the reference comes out empty (the hyperlink still works though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `caption` package cooperates with `listings`, using `\captionsetup[lstlistings]{…}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{labelsep=none, singlelinecheck=off}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\autoref{lst:some_code}.

\begin{lstlisting}[float,frame=single, caption={\empty}, label={lst:some_code}]
if (i<=0) then i := 1;
if (i>=0) then i := 0;
if (i<>0) then i := 0;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aha, I tried with `\captionsetup[listing]` or something. This is better.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.: As I was not too sure, I checked in the doc, that did the difference ;o)